# Why are accents accepted in sfValidatorEmail?

Tags: regex, email, symfony1, symfony-1.4

There was a bug in my application, apparently accents in an email address where not considered an error and the `sfMailer` was crashing an error because of this.

Digging through my code I realized I wasn't to blame.

`sfValidatorEmail` uses this regular expression:

```
const REGEX_EMAIL = '/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i';
```

Accents in the first part of the email are accepted.

Should `sfValidatorEmail` not accept accents or should `sfMailer` accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sfMailer should accept it. It is legitimate to have accents in the first part of the email address.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax) accents are valid. Off course, in practice, in webprogramming, I try to avoid anything (spaces, accents,...) that can upset the 'internet middle layer' (i.e. routers, servers, etc).